# Can DNA barcoding be employed to determine the order of an unidentified haematophagous parasite?

Tags: entomology, dna-sequencing, taxonomy, parasitology

Given: a specimen of an unidentified, highly adapted, haematophagous parasite, perhaps a species nova, contaminated with mammal blood and tissue.

[DNA barcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_barcoding) is readily used to identify [cryptic species complexes and superspecies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_complex), in [diet analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_barcoding#Diet_analysis_and_food_web_application) and for [food safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_barcoding#Barcoding_for_food_safety).

However, can DNA barcoding also be employed in a broader sense, up the taxonomic ladder, simply to identify the [insect order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect#Diversity) of a parasitic specimen contaminated with mammal host material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes--this is possible and has been done, e.g.:

- [DNA barcoding identifies Eimeria species and contributes to the phylogenetics
  of coccidian parasites (Eimeriorina, Apicomplexa, Alveolata)](https://biodiversitygenomics.net/site/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/2011%20-%20Ogedengbe%20-%20DNA%20barcoding%20identifies%20Ei.pdf) (doi: 10.1016/j.ijpara.2011.03.007)
- [Developing an Apicomplexan DNA Barcoding System to Detect Blood Parasites of Small Coral Reef Fishes](https://bioone.org/journals/journal-of-parasitology/volume-103/issue-4/16-93/Developing-an-Apicomplexan-DNA-Barcoding-System-to-Detect-Blood-Parasites/10.1645/16-93.full) (doi: 10.1645/16-93)
- [DNA barcoding and molecular identification of field-collected Culicoides larvae in the Niayes area of Senegal](https://parasitesandvectors.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13071-018-3176-y) (doi: 10.1186/s13071-018-3176-y)

There's also a review on the subject:

- [DNA barcoding of parasites and invertebrate disease vectors: what you don't know can hurt you](https://www.cell.com/trends/parasitology/comments/S1471-4922(03)00271-X) (doi: 10.1016/j.pt.2003.09.015)